# Erlang Message passing between process

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am writing code that reads two input files and checks if the words in the first file are present in the second file. I want to check elements of the list one by one via process message passing.

Here is my code:

```
start()->
    Pid2 = spawn(?MODULE,check2,[]),
    spawn(?MODULE,check1,[Pid2]).

check1(Pid2) ->
    {ok, Data} = file:read_file("input.txt"),
    B = binary:split(Data, [<<" ">>], [global]),
    K = [binary_to_list(Item) || Item <- B],
    [Pid2 ! Element || Element <- K].

check2() ->
    {ok,IoDevice} = file:open("check.txt", [read]),
    L = string:tokens(io:get_line(IoDevice,""), "! ."),
    receive
        Element ->
            case lists:member(Element,L)of
                true ->
                    io:format(Element);
                false ->
                    io:format("not_ok")
            end
    end.
```

The problem is that when I want to send an element of the list, it sends just the first element. How can I modify my code to send all strings and check them?

Comment: @Steve Vinoski: I expanded in this question much better and here is my code , I hope u can see my mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is that your `check2/0` function only receives a single element and then exits. It needs to loop to receive all elements, and it also needs something to tell it when to stop. Let's change the functions one by one below, starting with `start/0`:

```
start()->
    Pid2 = spawn(?MODULE,check2,[]),
    check1(Pid2).
```

The change here is that there's no need to spawn `check2/1` — it can just be run directly by `start/0`.

Next, here's our revised `check1/1` function:

```
check1(Pid2) ->
    {ok, Data} = file:read_file("input.txt"),
    B = binary:split(Data, [<<" ">>,<<"\n">>], [global,trim_all]),
    K = [binary_to_list(Item) || Item <- B],
    [Pid2 ! Element || Element <- K++[stop]].
```

First, we added newline to the split pattern, and also the `trim_all` option to get rid of empty elements from the split. We also appended the atom `stop` to the list of elements we send to `Pid2`. Let's look at our revised `check2/0` function to see why:

```
check2() ->
    {ok,IoDevice} = file:open("check.txt", [read]),
    L = string:tokens(io:get_line(IoDevice,""), "! .\n"),
    check2(L).
```

Note that we've split the original `check2/0` into two functions: `check2/0` and `check2/1`. This is because the `check2/1` function has to be recursive so it can receive all the elements sent to it:

```
check2(L) ->
    receive
        stop ->
            ok;
        Element ->
            case lists:member(Element,L)of
                true ->
                    io:format("found: ~s\n", [Element]);
                false ->
                    io:format("not found: ~s\n", [Element])
            end,
            check2(L)
    end.
```

Notice that inside the `receive` we first check to see if we've received the atom `stop`, and if we do, we exit the function. Otherwise, we receive and check an `Element`, and after that call `check2/1` recursively so it can receive either the next `Element` or the `stop` atom.

Comment: tnx so much  for ur help ,i have another problem i am trying to filter the found element , like if the found element is member of this list `["amazing","good","great","intresting","wonderful","valuable","super","excellent","admirable","awesome"]` print 1 otherwise if the Element is member of this list `["bad","garbage","terrible","horrible","boring","poor","weak","nok awful", "second-rate]` print (-1)...I wanted to do it in the `check2/1` by mixing two (case of ) statment but its not working...

Comment: You need to read and pass two lists, one for good entries and one for bad. Use `lists:member2` to check one list as you already do, but in the not found case do another case to check the other list, also with `lists:member/2`.